# How to change compositor in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, plasma

As title, what passages I have to do for changing compositor under Wayland? I was thinking to mask/disable some kwin.service but I can't found any using systemctl list-unit-files.
Maybe I would change something in some .config files?
No informations found on the KDE documentation or around the internet.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.